# Contactform7 passing server values to javascript

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin for the user to generate a pdf based on submitted (by the form) and server provided data.

I'd like to also show a "preview" after submission so I need to pass the custom fields to the client in order to get them in some js file.

This is what I have:

plugin rendering the pdf:

```
<?php

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'generate_pdf');
function generate_pdf($wpcf7) {

    $file_uri = 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
    require_once($file_uri);

    /* PDF file initialization */
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $today_date = "California, " . date("d  F  Y");
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $today_date, 0, 1, 'R');
    $name = $data['your-name'];
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    $pdf->Output(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/' . $name . '.pdf', 'F');
    $wpcf7['custom_field'] = 'CUSTOM VALUE';
    return $wpcf7;
}
?>
```

javascript file called on form submit:

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
        var data = $('form').serializeArray();
        var cleaned_data = {};
        for (item in data) {
            var name = data[item]['name'];
            if (name[0] != '_'){
                cleaned_data[name] = data[item]['value']; 
            }
        }
        var testInput = cleaned_data["your-name"];


})(jQuery);
```

In this last code I'd like to get the values passed by the php script, but  I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the PDF generation function is in functions.php and that you've enqueued the js, what you're looking to do is localization. You can read more about it here: [Localize scripts](http://www.webtipblog.com/localize-scripts-in-wordpress-to-use-php-variables-in-javascript/)